# How to change the background and size of the post footer, plus add a comment count?

Tags: button, comments, share, footer, social-networking

So my blog posts on my home page button have a Read More button, like so...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxYUy.png)

But they don't have anything in the post footer. Now, I found a way to add social media icons to my post-footer, but I also want to display my comment count. I also want to change the background of the post footer and the size (height?) of the post footer, to end up with something like this, minus the labels, that is.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4zi3.png)

I want to align the comment count to the left. And, again, I also figured out a way to include social media icons. But how do you change the background of the post-footer to have a different color? And how do you include the comment count? I tried changing the settings of my blog widget, and it didn't work. I suspect I may have accidentally removed the comment count by adding a conditional tag in the past, but I am not sure. So this is a weird logic—is their a conditional tag for removing comments in the homepage, so I can remove it from my HTML, if ever.

Please help!
And thank you, if ever. :)